# Cases of experienced psychoanalytics to stop taking supervisions

Tags: therapy, psychoanalysis

What are the examples of famous psychoanalysts, which were [supervisors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supervised_psychoanalysis#:%7E:text=A%20supervised%20psychoanalysis%20or%20psychoanalysis,a%20senior%2C%20more%20experienced%20colleague.) and did take supervisions themselves - i.e. consulted with colleagues on their own (supervisor's) clients. And what are the examples of those who did not and relied only their own opinion?